# Show/Hide DIV w/Unique SQL ID Values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to create a table w/lots of data to display, so I want to have a hidden div that holds more info.

I have almost everything set up, except I encountered a loop problem (hide/show only shows for first item on table), so I added an auto_increment ID on SQL (Row 13) so that I can easily assign unique IDs to each group on the table.

My display is this

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","blist");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM suspects");
      echo "<table class='style3' border='1'>
            <tr class='header'>
            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Picture</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Age</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Race</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Skin Color</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Height</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Build</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Eye Color</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Hair Color</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Aliases</strong></th>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr class='header'>";
      echo "<td>".$row[0]." ".$row[1]." ";
  echo "<div id='showhide'></div>";
  echo "</td>";
      echo "<td><img src='suspects/".$row[12]."' height=auto width=150 /></td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[5]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[6]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[7]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[8]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[9]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[10]."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td colspan='11'>";
  echo "<div id='hide_show'>";
  echo $row[11];
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The jQuery script for hide/show

```
var button_beg = '<button class="button" onclick="showhide()">'
var button_end = '</button>';
var show_button = 'Show More', hide_button = 'Show Less';
function showhide() {
    var div = document.getElementById( "hide_show" );
    var showhide = document.getElementById( "showhide" );
    if ( div.style.display !== "none" ) {
        div.style.display = "none";
        button = show_button;
        showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
    } else {
        div.style.display = "block";
        button = hide_button;
        showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
    }
}
function setup_button( status ) {
    if ( status == 'show' ) {
        button = hide_button;
    } else {
        button = show_button;
    }
    var showhide = document.getElementById( "showhide" );
    showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
}
window.onload = function () {
    setup_button( 'hide' );
    showhide(); // if setup_button is set to 'show' comment this line
}
```

This is where I'm stuck, I know I have to modify the jQuery so that each "showhide" has assigned $row[13] but I figured it wouldn't work because it isn't PHP

PS: I'm new to SQL/PHP

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:
  Only one pure javascript function  who receives the DIV's id to toggle:

```
function showHide(divId){
  var myDiv =document.getElementById(divId);
  if(myDiv){
      myDiv.style.diplay = myDiv.style.diplay.toLowerCase() =='none'?'':'none';
 }
}
```

Then in my php script:

```
echo "<button class='button' onclick='showHide(".$row['rowid'].")'>";
echo "<div class='myDivWhoContainsMoreData' id='".$row['rowid']."'>";
```

Please, adapt this idea to you case.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the same show/hide id for every row:

```
echo "<div id='showhide'></div>";
echo "<div id='hide_show'>";
```

Add an ID to those DIV's id so they are unique in the DOM:

```
echo "<div id='showhide".$row['morowid']."'></div>";
echo "<div id='hide_show".$row['morowid']."'>";
```

Then adjust your javascript accordingly.

Comment: I've had the showhide/hide_show with "$row[13]" already, but I don't know how I would go about modifying the js. I've tried replacing things, but then the script just stops working completely.

Answer (score 0):

#### the tabular data

Replace the `showhide` divs by the actual row id as you planned it, and use `showhide` for their class. Also give a class to `td` which contain data, as opposed to buttons. And make surrounding `tr` have the same id as the divs:

```
 <tr id='<?php echo $row[13]; ?>'>
 <td><div class='showhide' id='<?php echo $row[13]; ?>'></div></td>
 <td class=”data”>...</td>
 ...
</tr>
```

#### javascript code

You are using jquery, let's leverage its power with dom node selectors and events:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function toggle_div(id){
    $('tr#'+id).toggleClass('hidden');
    var b = $('button#'+id);
    switch (b.html()){
        case "hide":
            b.html("show");
            break;
        case "show":
            b.html("hide");
            break;
    }
}

// build all the buttons and bind onclick events
(function(){
    $('div.showhide').each(
        function(i,e){
            var id = $(e).attr('id');
            e.innerHTML="<button id='"+id+"' onclick=toggle_div(\””+id+"\”)'>hide</button>";
        }
    ):
})();
</script>
```

#### CSS

Add the following to your html, or css:

```
<style>

tr.hidden > td.data {
    display: none;
}

</style>
```

The javascript simply toggle a CSS class of the data table cells from the same row as the button being clicked. That class has for `display` property `none`, effectively hiding the cells belonging to it. You can tune that class CSS to your liking, without touching the code.